# error: cannot find symbol getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment()).commit();

Tags: java, android-studio

Why do I keep getting this error?
Here is my code and the error. I am trying to make a bottom navigation view for my app. and when the buttons are pressed the different fragments are accessed. Im working with android studio

```
package com.tylervis.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_search:
                    selectedFragment = new SearchFragment();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_add:
                    selectedFragment = null;
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostActivity.class));
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_fav:
                    selectedFragment = new NotificationFragment();
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_profile:
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit;
                    editor.putString("profiled", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                    editor.apply();
                    selectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                    break;

            }

            if(selectedFragment != null){
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,selectedFragment).commit();
            }

            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

Error

```
.../MainActivity.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
                                                                         ^
symbol:   class HomeFragment
location: class MainActivity
```

Its the same for all the other Fragments

Comment: It seems you don't import the class `HomeFragment` in your fragment source files. Try adding this class to your import list.

Comment: Still not finding the solution ?